# Control Multiple dropdown box by one main dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to create a main drop down box which control multiple drop down box. This multiple drop down box created in loop so i need dynamic script which works on class or id.

example -

```
<form method="post" name="postage">
Select All      
      <select id="options1" name="se1"  >
            <option value="0" >-- Select --</option>
            <option value="Royal Mail">Royal mail</option>
            <option value="USP courier">USP courier</option>
            <option value="Standard courier">Standard courier</option>
            <option value="DHL courier">DHL courier</option>
      </select>

Select Manually-       
       <select id="options2" name="se2"  >
            <option value="0" >-- Select --</option>
            <option value="Royal Mail">Royal mail</option>
            <option value="USP courier">USP courier</option>
            <option value="Standard courier">Standard courier</option>
            <option value="DHL courier">DHL courier</option>
      </select>
        <select id="options3" name="se3"  >
            <option value="0" >-- Select --</option>
            <option value="Royal Mail">Royal mail</option>
            <option value="USP courier">USP courier</option>
            <option value="Standard courier">Standard courier</option>
            <option value="DHL courier">DHL courier</option>
      </select>
        <select id="options3" name="se4"  >
            <option value="0" >-- Select --</option>
            <option value="Royal Mail">Royal mail</option>
            <option value="USP courier">USP courier</option>
            <option value="Standard courier">Standard courier</option>
            <option value="DHL courier">DHL courier</option>
      </select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit_result" />
</form>
```

I found one script but i don't know where to change -

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
$('.west-yorkshire').change(function({
     var value = $(this).val();
      $('.className').each(function(
       $(this).val(value);
        alert(value);
     ));
}));
}//]]>  

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve ? http://jsfiddle.net/9R9DV/2/

Changed some JS code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#options1').change(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     $('.manual').each(function(){
       $(this).val(value);
     });
 });
```

});

and classes to HTML code

```
 <select class="manual" id="options2" name="se2"  >
 ...
 <select class="manual" id="options3" name="se3"  >
 ...
```

etc.

Comment: That's piece of cake... Believe me! :)